# How to load default wordpress scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm displaying a custom WP_List_Table on a plugin page, and would like to use the bulk actions. However, the top checkbox doesn't let me select all checkboxes below.

I have narrowed the problem down to the fact that `wp-admin/js/common.js` is not loaded. I tried:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'common' );
```

and also tried adding it as a dependency to another script:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-script',
    plugins_url( '/js/my-script.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'common' )
);
```

but it's not loading. Any suggestions?

---

Edit: it appears I had not tested well enough: the first method doesn't work, but the second method - adding it as dependency - actually does work!

Comment: How do you execute `wp_enqueue_script()`?

Comment: via the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook. All other scripts load properly, just the common.js is not loaded.

Comment: Are you getting errors/notices/anything in the browser console?

Comment: nope, all clear! To elaborate on my previous comment: the 'my-script' from my question loads, it just doesn't load the 'common' dep.

Comment: Are you able to load any other default scripts found here? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Examples

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't load under `load-scripts.php`?

Comment: I guess the question is now why do you think it isn't loading, because 1) your checkboxes don't work, or 2) because you have looked through the source and can't find the script?

Comment: I can't find the script in the console. On normal pages it is included in load-scripts.php but on this page it isn't.

Comment: @Steven - yes, jquery and jquery-ui-tabs for example are loading fine (as a dep. to my script, into `load-scripts.php`).

Comment: Correction, they appear to be loading, but not into load-scripts.php...

Comment: solved... sorry not testing properly! My mistake!